# JQuery continuous image carousel only moving one image at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently working on an image carousel and I believe it is 99% done, except for one thing... I can only move one picture at a time, and then I have to rehover in order to keep the slider going. So is there some sort of jump statement or goto statement that I can use to continually run the loops?

Here is what I have so far :

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjyuA/)

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').each(function(){
        if($(this).width() < $(this).children('ul').width()){
            $(this).children('carrow').each(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
    });

    $('.carousel').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.carrow').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('carrow-hover');
        });
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('.carrow').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('carrow-hover');
        });
    });

    $('.carrow').hover(function(){
        var SD = 210;   
        var $carousel = $(this).parent();
        var $ul = $carousel.children('ul');
        var distance = SD;
        var time = 2500;
        var rate = distance/time;

        //When animation is completed, Jump back to here

        distance = Math.abs($ul.position().left);

        if($(this).hasClass('left-arrow')){
            if(distance == 0) {
                $ul.css({left: -210});
                $ul.prepend($ul.children('li:last-child'));
            } else {
                time = distance/rate;
            }
            $ul.stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, time, 'linear');
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('right-arrow')){
            if(distance != 0){
                distance = SD - distance;

                time = distance/rate;
            }
            $ul.stop().animate({
                left: -210
            }, time, 'linear', function(){
                $ul.append($ul.children('li:first-child'));
                $ul.css({left: 0});
            });
        }   
    }, function(){
        $(this).parent().children('ul').stop();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate animation routine in it's own function, e.g.

```
function myAnimate(that){
// animation goes here
}
```

And call itself as a callback function at the animation end

```
$ul.stop().animate({
   left: 0
}, time, 'linear', function(){myAnimate(that)});
```

This way as soon as one animation ends - the other begins

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bjyuA/1/**

Comment: I actually like this a lot. I managed to figure it out on my own, but I did it a little differently, so it made it a little more complex because I was only creating the function for the loop part that I wanted instead of the function as a whole. I think this is a more reliable answer than what mine was

Comment: @yuriy-galanter +1 `that` http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/yC3ka/ `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`

Comment: @guest271314 yup. context is everything

Answer (score 0):

All I did was loop the part I had wanted and created a few extra dependencies which `Yuriy` had fixed, but I figured I would share my approach as well.

```
$('.carrow').hover(function(){
    var SD = 210;
    var $this = $(this);
    var $carousel = $(this).parent();
    var $ul = $carousel.children('ul');
    var distance = SD;
    var time = 2500;
    var rate = distance/time;

    distance = Math.abs($ul.position().left);

    continue_scroll = function(dist) {
        time = 2500;
        if(arguments.length != 0){
            distance = dist;
        }

        if($this.hasClass('left-arrow')){
            if(distance == 0) {
                time = 2500;
            } else {
                time = distance/rate;
            }
            $ul.stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, time, 'linear', function(){
                $ul.prepend($ul.children('li:last-child'));
                $ul.css({left: -210});
                continue_scroll(210);
            });
        }
        else if($this.hasClass('right-arrow')){
            if(distance != 0 && arguments.length == 0){
                distance = SD - distance;                   
                time = distance/rate;
            }
            $ul.stop().animate({
                left: -210
            }, time, 'linear', function(){
                $ul.append($ul.children('li:first-child'));
                $ul.css({left: 0});
                continue_scroll(0);
            });
        }
    }

    continue_scroll();

}, function(){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').stop();
});
```